# How to receive non-selected query parameter in Primefaces AutoComplete?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

**AutoCompleteView**

```
@ManagedBean
public class AutoCompleteView {

private Query selectedQuery;

private String searchTerm;    

private List<Query> selectedQueries;

@Inject
private AutoQueryService service;

public List<Query> completeQuery(String query) {
    List<Query> allQueries = service.getQueries();
    List<Query> suggestions = new ArrayList<Query>();
    for(Query suggestion : allQueries) {
        if(suggestion.getName().startsWith(query)){
            suggestions.add(suggestion);
        }
    }
    return suggestions;
}

  public void search() {

    if (selectedQuery != null && !selectedQuery.getName().isEmpty()) {
        searchTerm = selectedQuery.getName();
        // execute here ...
    }else {
        // ... how to fill the value of "seachTerm"? 
    } 
}

public Query getSelectedQuery() {
    System.out.println("selected: " + selectedQuery);
    return selectedQuery;
}

public void setSelectedQuery(Query selectedQuery) {
    this.selectedQuery = selectedQuery;
}

public List<Query> getSelectedQueries() {
    return selectedQueries;
}

public void setService(AutoQueryService service) {
    this.service = service;
}

public String getSearchTerm() {
        return searchTerm;
   }
}
```

**test.xhtml**

```
<f:view>
        <h:form >
            <h:outputText value="Type Query :"/>
            <p:autoComplete id="queryPojo"
                        value="#{autoCompleteView.selectedQuery}"
                        completeMethod="#{autoCompleteView.completeQuery}" var="query"
                        itemLabel="#{query.name}" itemValue="#{query}"
                        converter="queryConverter" />

            <h:commandButton id="search" value="Search" action="#{autoCompleteView.search()}"/>  
        </h:form>

         <h:outputText value="#{autoCompleteView.selectedQuery}"/>
         <h:outputText value="#{autoCompleteView.searchTerm}"/>

    </f:view>
```

When user selects a suggested query, this query will be printed out in browser:

```
<h:outputText value="#{autoCompleteView.selectedQuery}"/>
<h:outputText value="#{autoCompleteView.searchTerm}"/>
```

However, if it doesn't force user to select a query, and just type his owns, and then execute a search, the "selectedQuery" variable will be null. How can I receive the typed query term, whether the user selects the suggestion or not.

**POJO converter**

```
@FacesConverter("queryConverter")
public class QueryConverter implements Converter {

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String value) {
        if(value != null && value.trim().length() > 0) {
            try {
                QueryService service = (QueryService) fc.getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().get("queryService");
                return service.getQueries().get(Integer.parseInt(value));
            } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion Error", "Not a valid query."));
            }
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object object) {
        if(object != null) {
            return String.valueOf(((Query) object).getId());
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: @Geinmachi, I added the commandAction. It is supposed to execute a search function when the searchTerm value is filled. How to fill the value when no suggestion is selected?

Comment: Why is value in `p:autoComplete` of type `Query`? If you follow [examples from showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml) you should be able save the value when no suggestion is selected, just make `selectedQuery` field `String`.

Comment: @Geinmachi  I am dealing with POJO example, in the demo, it is also not String type, but Theme (See 'theme1' example), which is a class defined in th Theme.java. The String example is different.

Comment: Did you check your converter? Does it work when user chooses not suggested value? Try to debug it.

Comment: The same thing. When no suggestion is selected, the 'theme1' variable will be null in the PrimeFaces showcase demo.

Comment: You are right, it does not work in PrimeFaces showcase, but it is due to converter. When you type "a" and choose "Afterdark" then value in converter is "0" and it fetches element by index in list. When you type "Afterdark" then value in converter is "Afterdark" and obviously it's not valid index. Add to your page `h:messages` or `p:messages` and update it after you submit form, then you will see conversion error. As I said debug your converter, print out incoming values (when selected and just typed) and you will see difference.

Comment: @Geinmachi, then how can I possibly fix this issue? Is there a loophole in the demo code? This is a very common scenario, where users sometimes don't bother to use suggestions, and indeed in AutoComplete there is a forceSuggestion setting.

Comment: The key is to write converter which works in both cases: selected and typed values. Post your converter and then maybe it can be rewritten accordingly.

Comment: I posted the convert, which is almost the same as from the the showcase demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of POJO objects, `p:autoComplete` inserts object's value as a `String` returned by JSF converter. I will refer to [this PrimeFaces showcase example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml) which is analogous to your case with one exception, you **don't force user to select option**.

This is the converter:

```java
@FacesConverter("themeConverter")
public class ThemeConverter implements Converter {

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String value) {
        if(value != null && value.trim().length() > 0) {
            try {
                ThemeService service = (ThemeService) fc.getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().get("themeService");
                return service.getThemes().get(Integer.parseInt(value));
            } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion Error", "Not a valid theme."));
            }
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object object) {
        if(object != null) {
            return String.valueOf(((Theme) object).getId());
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }   
}
```

When user types in "a" and selects first suggested element ("Afterdark" in this case), the value of hidden input corresponding to `p:autoComplete` is **0**. It's 0 because object represented by "Afterdark" is first in collection, and the value is obtained from `getAsString` method (which returns index of object). When user submits form, then `value` in `getAsObject` method is **0** and the correct object is found in collection by this index. Everything works fine here because value in form was supplied by converter.

When users types "Afterdark" (it's not selected from suggested elements) then the value of hidden input corresponding to `p:autoComplete` is **Afterdark**. On form submit converter tries to find objects by index given in `value` parameter of `getAsObject` method. This is the moment when it fails because of **Afterdark** value instead of **0**. THe `ConverterException` is thrown and if you have `h:messages` or `p:messages` which is updated after form submit you will see error "Conversion Error". To make it work the value returned by `getAsString` method has to be same as the value typed by user. Instead of index, the property `displayName` of class `Theme` can be used **but the values have to be unique, if they are not, the first one will be always chosen**. But still, the value typed in by user has to be in collection of objects. If you want a user to be able to type anything and still have the value (POJO), you need to create such object and return it. This is the implementation which allows user to type "Afterdark" and the correct theme (object) will be found in collection, as well as "create" new theme (object) by typing in random `String` like "qwerty123".

```java
@FacesConverter("themeConverter")
public class ThemeConverter implements Converter {

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String value) {
        if (value != null && value.trim().length() > 0) {
            ThemeService service = (ThemeService) fc.getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().get("themeService");
            List<Theme> themes = service.getThemes();

            for (Theme theme : themes) {
                if (theme.getDisplayName().equals(value)) {
                    return theme;
                }
            }

            return new Theme(((Long) System.currentTimeMillis()).intValue(), value, value);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object object) {
        if (object != null) {
            return ((Theme) object).getDisplayName();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Line 
`return new Theme(((Long) System.currentTimeMillis()).intValue(), value, value);` returns new object when typed in value is not present in suggested options. Comparing values is case sensitive, for case insensitive version you can use `toLowerCase()` like so: 
`if (theme.getDisplayName().toLowerCase().equals(value.toLowerCase()))`.

Comment: Great explanation on this matter, very thorough. Can I say that the purpose of System.currentTimeMillis() is to simply create a random artificial ID that is required for creating the object?

Comment: Yes, I used example from PrimeFaces showcase and it requires ID in constructor.

Comment: Instead of using System.currentTimeMillis(), can I simply use a fixed value, i.e. '0' always? I thought the ID in this case doesn't matter. I am trying to understand this process better. Thanks.

Comment: ID does matter, in fact everything in this object does not matter except for the `String` which typed user (`displayName` in this case, you should process it further in managed bean). The point is you **have to** create object if it does not exist (it's not present in list, suggestions).

Comment: return new Theme(((Long) System.currentTimeMillis()).intValue(), value, value); Where does the returned object go? Does it go to some List where the index has to be unique? I thought it will go directly to the JSF view and be presented to the user.

Comment: I meant I might create Theme like new Theme (0, "dog", "dog"); new Theme(0, "pig", "pig"); new Theme(0, "cat", "cat"). Does this make sense?

Comment: Object returned by `getAsObject` method goes to the field which is under `value` attribute, in your case it would be `autoCompleteView.selectedQuery`. These objects would make sense, but ID should be unique, JPA should provide one if you want to persist them.

Comment: Is it possible to create an ID by System.currentTimeMillis()).intValue() that already exists in the current list of suggestions?

Comment: Theoretically yes, practically not really. Objects would have to be created in the same moment, either by fast server or multi threading. In this case always one object is created and this is not concurrent process, so not.

Comment: Great. This example should be included in the PF AutoComplete demo, since in many search cases, users don't have to be forced to select a value from a list.

Comment: I believe it works like this for `String` values, not POJO objects. You could use this `String` value to create object in managed bean instead of using POJO and creating it in converter. As a personal opinion I think you miss the point of `p:autoComplete` with POJOs and what you are trying to do can be done simpler.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106296/discussion-between-user697911-and-geinmachi).